# KSOAP runtime exception in android

Tags: android, ksoap2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot serialize issue in KSOAP in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664051/cannot-serialize-issue-in-ksoap-in-android)

I am calling one web service in my application,in that i am setting the input for that SOAP request as follows:

```
 PropertyInfo usrid =new PropertyInfo();
            usrid.setName("LoginID");
            usrid.setValue(userid);
            usrid.setType(String.class);
            authentication.addProperty(usrid);        

            PropertyInfo pass =new PropertyInfo();
            pass.setName("Password");
            pass.setValue(password);
            pass.setType(String.class);
            authentication.addProperty(pass);    

            request.addProperty("authentication", authentication);

            PropertyInfo no =new PropertyInfo();
            no.setName("No");
            no.setValue("28448347");
            no.setType(String.class); 
            request.addProperty("Str",no);
```

But i am receiving the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize:no
```

Comment: What happens if you delete PropertyInfo no? Does it still throw an error

Comment: It shows SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to read request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 304). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The specified type was not recognized: name='authentication',

Comment: Well i don't see an "authentication" property in your code.

Comment: Post `wsdl` of your web-service here

Comment: Hi user1378730  r u asking this   SoapObject authentication = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"authentication");

Comment: Hi StenaviN ,dont mistake me i am new to this SOAP and android,so wsdl means r u asking for the Request structure of my SOAP??